# Angular 8 Parse Json Object

Tags: json, typescript, angular8

A rather basic Angular 8 question I assume, but here goes:

I am using `http.get()` to pull a JSON response from the server. If I save the response as a variable, e.g. jsonResponse, and put that response into my HTML component as `{{jsonResponse | json}}` I get the anticipated nice json object, e.g. `{ 'hithere': {'this is me' : 'no really'}}`.

But I cannot seem to get the same nice Object to loop through in the TS/JS side of things. Can someone point me in the correct direction so that I can do something like. `jsonResponse.hithere`?

Comment: People use JSON to mean everything and nothing. JSON is a text format. When you use `http.get` in Angular, what you get in the response is an array or object, which the parsed result of the JSON returned by your sever. The `json` pipe calls `JSON.stringify` on that object and shows the results. If you cannot get data from your `jsonResponse`, you may be accessing the response incorrectly. Provide more information about what you've tried and the errors you're getting, and perhaps we can help.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the object using JSON.parse(obj) and then loop/traverse through its leafs.